# While using Ruby Koans my rake was aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using Ruby Koans and all of a sudden my rake was aborted. I am concerned that it wasn't setup properly. What I am posting is what was in the terminal. Any help is greatly appreciated`

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb
>   /Users/~/koans/koans/about_methods.rb:21:in `eval': (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
>   assert_equal 5, my_global_method (2, 3)
>                                     ^
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/about_methods.rb:21:in`test_sometimes_missing_parentheses_are_ambiguous'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:441:in `meditate'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:513:in`block in walk'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:524:in `block (3 levels) in each_step'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:522:in`each'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:522:in `block (2 levels) in each_step'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:521:in`each'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:521:in `each_with_index'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:521:in`block in each_step'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:519:in `catch'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:519:in`each_step'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:512:in `walk'
>       from /Users/~/koans/koans/neo.rb:534:in`block in '
>   rake aborted!
>   Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
>   /Users/~/koans/koans/Rakefile:10:in `block in '

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space after `my_global_method`.